# How to Calculate a Date in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

```
let date1 = "2017-02-09 11:51:07"
let date2 = **I need now time code**
```

How to Calculate this?
looks like "10 minutes ago", "1 hours ago", " 1 day ago"

Anyone help me please~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this playground

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

// Given a date as a string
let dateString = "2017-02-09 11:51:07"

// To turn it into a date we can use a date formatter
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

// Make sure the formatter is using the correct format for your date string
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

// Attempt to create a date from the string using our date formatter
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {
    fatalError("Unable to create date from string \(dateString) with format \(dateFormatter.dateFormat)")
}

// Calendar can do all kinds of things with dates
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

// Date() By itself will give us "now" date
let now = Date()

// We can ask the calendar to give us the hours and minutes between now and the date we parsed
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date, to: now)

// If getting the hours was succesful we can use them
if let hours = components.hour {
    print("\(hours) hours ago")
}

// same with minutes
if let minutes = components.minute {
    print("\(minutes) minutes ago")
}

// you can also try using DateComponentsFormatter

let componentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
componentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .minute, .hour]
componentsFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 2
componentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full

if let fromString = componentsFormatter.string(from: date, to: now) {
    print("Parsed date was \(fromString) ago.")
}
```

Using the `Date`, `DateFormatter`, `Calendar`, `DateComponentsFormatter`, and `DateComponents` APIs you should be able to pull this off.

Comment: `hh:mm:ss` is wrong. hh means 01-12. It should be HH (00-23).

Comment: Assuming he's using the `HH` format, you're right! He's used `11` in his question so it's ambiguous what format he really needs unless he gives more data!

Comment: not ambiguous there is no AM PM info. You need to use `HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Ok yea you're probably right, I'll edit the post. @Travis if you're unsure about the date formatting or you have other formats to work with, http://nsdateformatter.com is a pretty nice site to figure out the correct format.

Comment: @AndrewCarter However, this code works only in the playground. How do I get it to work within the ViewController class?